# Learning SQL server and finding difficulty in downloading extensions

Tags: sql-server

Image 1 is from Udemy course where it shows to download the extensions of SQL reporting/analyzing and integration by Microsoft.
but when I am trying to do the same thing it's not shown. and in the course it was SQL 2019, so is there any difference.
Can anybody help my out as  I always face some issue regarding SQL when I am learning it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio is the second screen shot from?

Comment: Also in the course it downloads integration/reporting and analysis extensions but either is not shown when I am trying to download and mine is VS 2022

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15): *"The extensions for Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects are not available for Visual Studio 2022 at this time."* You need to install VS 2019.

Comment: Thanks @larnu, I have uninstalled eveerything that I have installed yesterday and will reinstall 2019 version as shown, and if Wil ahve any issue , will again connect. thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately the community here cannot help with 500 errors on the Microsoft website. Though I just went to the Visual Studio website and manage to download the VS 2019 Community installer file, from my "Your Downloads" section, fine in my Windows 11 VM.

Comment: In last 2 images, as per course I have done everything step by step as per course, but when I am trying to install the same on my PC, its not showing any folder, neither its accepting different folder.
Have tried every folder, but it is showing the same error
@Larnu please help me

Comment: You've completely malformed the question now. *"Image 1 is from udemy course"* but it's now of a error. If your course is generating errors, you need to talk to your tutor.

Comment: No, As per the course, when he is trying to download sql installation media, it can directly select the location, but whn I am trying to do the same on my PC, it is showing error.
if you can relate, 3rd image is from udemy and 1st image is from my PC

Comment: That isn't what your question says. It's completely changed from when I looked at it yesterday. Like I said, if you're having problems, I suggest talking to your tutor.

Comment: Yesterday issue was resolved totally, have done 2019 VS. And thats the thing, I have actually not bought this course, I applied a coupon code, and got free.

Comment: This question was previously about Visual Studio and now it's about SSMS; it's a *completely* different question, and changing the question like that is frowned upon by the community. [Don't be a Chameleon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal). If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: @Larnu, I have asked a new question, can you have a look and help me.
I really wanted to learn SQL, I have tried previously also, but there was 1 issue or other I faced either with postgresql.
But now anyhow wanted to learn.